# Order inside executeBindings Databind android

Tags: android, data-binding

I am using databind to set two spinners

```
Spinner 1
 id = SpinnerY
 attr={databind.id}
Spinner 2
 id = SpinnerA
 attr={databind.id}
```

and i need garantee (becaouse values of SpinnerA are loaded on onchage of SpinnerY ) order of execution, but i see inside executeBindings and he execute in order alphabetic id, in this case SpinnerA will be executed bind after SpinnerY.

ow i can change this?

--- Real Code---

```
<br.com.egsys.pmmgmobile.componets.MySpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spUfVeiculo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Estado"
                        app:dao="EstadoDAO"
                        app:loadedValue="@{container.veiculo.idEstado}" />


                    <br.com.egsys.pmmgmobile.componets.MySpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spMunicipioVeiculo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Município"
                        app:dao="MunicipioDAO"
                        app:loadedValue="@{container.veiculo.idMunicipio}"/>
```

executeBindings (automatic generated)

```
br.com.egsys.pmmgmobile.componets.MySpinner.setValues(this.spMunicipioVeiculo, (java.lang.String)null, idMunicipioVeiculoCo);  

    br.com.egsys.pmmgmobile.componets.MySpinner.setValues(this.spUfVeiculo, (java.lang.String)null, idEstadoVeiculoConta);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Data Binding has no guaranteed order for when values are set. You can try to avoid the need by untying the two spinners and instead tie the values to the backing data instead.

You don't explicitly show any of your `setAdapter()` calls, so I expect that you do that in code instead of through data binding. Because 2-way data binding is supported on `android:selectedItemPosition`, you can use that in your binding expression and get what you need.

This is not going to be a complete example, but I hope it gives you enough to get you going.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spUfVeiculo" ...
         android:adapter="@{container.veiculo.spUfAdapter}"
         android:selectedItemPosition="@={container.veiculo.idEstado}"/>
<Spinner android:adapter="@{container.veiculo.getMunicipioAdapter(spUfVeiculo.selectedItemPosition)}"
         android:selectedItemPosition="@={container.veiculo.idMunipio}"
         ... />
```

You would need a method `getMunicipioAdapter(int)` on veiculo. Because I don't know your specific data model, I can't say that is the best way to do it. You may also prefer to have a BindingAdapter to mutates your Adapter so you can use a separate attribute:

```
<Spinner android:adapter="@{container.veiculo.municipioAdapter}"
         app:adapterPosition="@{spUfVeiculo.selectedItemPosition}"
         android:selectedItemPosition="@={container.veiculo.idMunipio}"
         ... />
```

And then add the BindingAdapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("adapterPosition")
public static void setAdapterPosition(AdapterView view, int position) {
    MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) view.getAdapter();
    // modify adapter so that it changes the values based on the position
    // from spUfVeiculo
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i am not talking about order of parameter inside of method, this is alright, i am talking about order of called method inside executeBindings , in my case i need he execute first spinner of xml on databind and after another one, inside databind use id on order alphabetic to call it.

Comment: Yes, there is no guaranteed order for those. Sorry. The best way to solve the problem is to avoid the necessity for ordering.